# Android - Tracking memory leaks from BitmapFactory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to fix memory leaks problems / understand what is happening in my app. I reduced my code to this simple test (loading a huge image of 13575x8145 px with an inSampleSize of 6) :

```
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Documents/test_13575x8145.png");
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 6;
Utils.printMemoryUsage();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
b.recycle();
b = null;
Utils.printMemoryUsage();
```

Utils.printMemoryUsage() is the following method :

```
public static void printMemoryUsage() {

    //Getting the runtime reference from system
    float mb = 1024*1024;
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Log.i("Utils", "------------------------");
    Log.i("Utils", "Memory usage :");
    Log.i("Utils", "Used Memory:" + (float)(runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);
    Log.i("Utils", "Free Memory:" + (float)runtime.freeMemory() / mb);
    Log.i("Utils", "Total Memory:" + (float)runtime.totalMemory() / mb);
    Log.i("Utils", "Max Memory:" + (float)runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
    Log.i("Utils", "------------------------");
}
```

Which outputs for my sample code :

```
11-17 22:53:08.631: I/Utils(12974): ------------------------
11-17 22:53:08.631: I/Utils(12974): Memory usage :
11-17 22:53:08.631: I/Utils(12974): Used Memory:7.999222
11-17 22:53:08.631: I/Utils(12974): Free Memory:0.82084656
11-17 22:53:08.631: I/Utils(12974): Total Memory:8.820282
11-17 22:53:08.636: I/Utils(12974): Max Memory:64.0
11-17 22:53:08.636: I/Utils(12974): ------------------------
...
11-17 22:53:15.276: I/Utils(12974): ------------------------
11-17 22:53:15.276: I/Utils(12974): Memory usage :
11-17 22:53:15.276: I/Utils(12974): Used Memory:20.07035
11-17 22:53:15.276: I/Utils(12974): Free Memory:0.62480164
11-17 22:53:15.276: I/Utils(12974): Total Memory:20.695282
11-17 22:53:15.281: I/Utils(12974): Max Memory:64.0
11-17 22:53:15.281: I/Utils(12974): ------------------------
```

Is it normal ? I know that the call to recycle() does not take effect immediately, but even if I print the memory usage later, the memory is not released.
Thanks

EDIT : If I run the code several times, the heap does not grow again (it is normal, the heap is big enough to load the image again). But still the memory seems not released (the runtime.freeMemory() is still near to 0)